# How do you know if a new list was created or just modifed?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm confused about this.

Say I have a function that is called everythird, and that takes a list as a parameter, and returns the every third element.

```
def everythird(l):
    return l[0::3]
```

And if I input everythird([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) and get back [1, 4, 7]. Is that considered a new list, modified list, or neither?

Also do methods modify or create new lists? What about splicing?

Comment: which methods do you refer to? and which splicing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slices create shallow copies. It's a different list, but with the same elements. This means you can append to it, or reset elements by index without affecting the original, but if you mutate an element the effect will be seen in the original.

Since your elements are immutable, you won't notice this, but consider the following:

```
>>> def everythird(l):
        return l[0::3]

>>> x = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> y = everythird(x)
>>> y[0].append(1)
>>> x
[[1, 1], [2], [3]]
```

The only way to have a completely different list is through `copy.deepcopy`

> Also do methods modify or create new lists? What about splicing?

`list` methods are usually inplace like `.append` and mutate the instance itself, the exception being Python 3's `list.copy` which is the equivalent to `seq[:]` or `list(seq)`.

Comment: Thanks jamylak! So if I'm getting you, .pop, .__mul__, .remove, .reverse all mutate/modify the original list?

Comment: @user2489861 Yes except `.__mul__` which shallow copies as well